# Who were "Dawson and Wilson" (mentioned as authors of an embryonic postmortem examination method)?

Tags: pathology, anatomy, pathophysiology

A sentence from a Russian text I'm translating:

> Following the drug administration period, the pregnant animals were euthanized in order to examine the embryos **using the method developed by Dawson and Wilson**.

That made me curious. Who were they? Google fails to bring up both these surnames at once in response to queries like "Dawson Wilson embryo necropsy" etc. Maybe one of them developed an embryo examination technique, and the other perfected it?

Comment: So this isn't a citation? Those surnames are not followed by a year, like Dawson and Wilson, 1972?

Comment: @LinuxBlanket - no, there is no reference, no footnote. There's another mention of Dawson several pages down the document - a mention of "embryos stained using the technique developed by Dawson".

Comment: I updated my answer. I couldn't find any specific reference to some article by Wilson, but I think I found out which Wilson is it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This article (A Note on the Staining of the Skeleton of Cleared Specimens with Alizarin Red S)](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.3109/10520292609115636) looks to be the one by Dawson.

Update: I think the Wilson your text is referring to is [James G. Wilson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_G._Wilson), an important researcher on terathology. I can't find any reference to a single article, though.